# Get ID using the name and folder of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm copying some spreadsheets and those copies need to be edited (transform formulas into raw data) and I CAN'T edit the source spreadsheet.

I'm creating a simple copy of the source spreadsheet:

```
 DriveApp.getFileById("ID HERE").makeCopy(name, folder);
```

So, at this point I have the name and folder of the new spreadsheet but I need to how to access and edit it. Maybe getting it's ID or URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get the id of the file that you created using copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely what you are looking for is

```
var id = DriveApp.getFileById("ID HERE").makeCopy(name, folder).getId();
```

or alternatively a general case

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var id = file.getId();
}

// do something with id here
```

If there are multiple files with the same name, you may encounter the issue of making a copy of the wrong file.

Comment: Thank you but i'm already copying the correct file, the problem is to edit that copy. I don't know how to get the ID or URL of that copy.